# How to keep a timestamp for each database connection in an application using Java?

Tags: java, database, connection

So, i have an application where I need to update the database connection class. All i need to do is put timestamps to each DB connection?

Comment: For what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I need to avoid connecting to the database every time ... I want to reuse the connection...but by not using Apache imapala connection pool.

Instead I want to put some timestamp for each connection.